# Why is there no probability measure $\mu:2^{[0,1]}\to [0,1]$ on $[0,1]$ s.t. $\mu([0,x])=x$?

Tags: measure-theory

Why is there no probability measure $\mu:2^{[0,1]}\to [0,1]$ on $[0,1]$ s.t. $\mu([0,x])=x$  and $\mu$ is invariant under translation ?

---

**Attempts**

Let $\mathcal B([0,1])$ the Borel set of $[0,1]$. I know that on $\mathcal B([0,1])$, there is a unique measure s.t. $m([0,x])=x$, it's the Lebesgue measure. We can extend $m$ on $\mathcal M([0,1])$ the set of Lebesgue measurable set on $[0,1]$.

**Question:** Now, why there are no measures $\mu:2^{[0,1]}\to [0,1]$ s.t. $\mu(A)=m(A)$ for all $A\in \mathcal M([0,1])$ ?

I know that there are always $A,B$ s.t. $m^*(A\cup B)<m^*(A)+m^*(B)$. So, I think I should prove that if such $\mu$ exist, then there is an exterior measure $\mu^*:2^{[0,1]}\to [0,1]$ and $\mu^*=m^*$, but I failed to prove it.

**My theorem is the following one**
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, but perhaps since there is no finite translation invariant measure on $2^{[0,1]}$ extending the Lebesgue measure, it will be enough to show that such a $\mu$ would be in some sense translation invariant.

Comment: @GEdgar: Sorry but I don't understand any word / concept of your comment... "Who says there is no such measure? " : It's one of my exercise (bachelor 3rd year).

Comment: Have you seen the construction of Vitali sets?

Comment: Yes I did. @Joe

Comment: So maybe I’m missing something, but how is your question different? Can’t you just create a Vitali set in $[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}]$ and show that it cannot be measurable?

Answer (score 1):

Who says there is no such measure?

Certainly if $\mathfrak c$ is not a real-valued measurable cardinal, then there is no such measure.  (For example, if CH holds.)

But it is believed that "$\mathfrak c$ is a real-valued measurable cardinal" is consistant with ZFC; in that case there is such a measure.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Real-valued_measurable

---

So ... Assume $\mathfrak c$ is a real-valued measurable cardinal.  That is: there is a probability measure $\mu : \mathcal P(\mathbb R) \to [0,1]$, where $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ is the power set of $\mathbb R$.

It is known (ref?) that $\mathfrak c$ is not a $2$-valued measurable cardinal.  So the nondecreasing map $\varphi : \mathbb R \to [0,1]$ defined by $\varphi(t) = \mu\big((-\infty,t]\big)$ has no jumps, thus $\varphi$ is continuous.  By the intermediate value theorem, $\varphi$ maps $[-\infty,+\infty]$ onto $[0,1]$.

Define the "image measure" $\mathbb P = \varphi_*(\mu)$ as usual.  That is, for $E \subset [0,1]$ let $\mathbb P(E) = \mu\big(\varphi^{-1}(E)\big)$.  Then $\mathbb P$ is a probability measure defined on $\mathcal P([0,1])$ with the property $\mathbb P\big([0,t]\big) =t$ for $0 \le t \le 1$.

Comment: So, could you provide a probability measure $\mathbb P$ on $[0,1]$ s.t. $\mathbb P([0,x])=x$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ ?

Comment: @user657324 You cannot give an explicit example (read the Wikipedia page!) but we cannot disprove it exists either .So your exercise is wrong as stated: you cannot solve it (or you would have found a contradiction in ZFC, so in most of mathematics!)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I add the theorem from my lecture. So this theorem is wrong ? Or is there something I forgot ?

Comment: @user657324 No, but that adds the extra stronger condition (1) that $m$ is translation invariant.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: oups, sorry. (I'm really new in this king of thing... for me this condition was automatically satisfied). But indeed, it's not (for instance, dirac measure).